# confusion on setting fabric path

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to run this command

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem" -C mychannel -n ledger -c '{"Args":["CreateAsset","asset1","blue","5","tom","35"]}'
```

And i get this error

```
Fatal error when initializing core config : Could not find config file. Please make sure that FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set to a path which contains core.yaml
```

I am following this tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_tutorial.html#enable-couchdb-in-hyperledger-fabric and i am confused about where i did wrong.

my core.yml file is set into this location
[core.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P6Rg.png)
I didnt change anything so far.

Comment: Make sure FABRIC_CFG_PATH is set in the same terminal you are running peer commands. `echo $FABRIC_CFG_PATH`

Comment: You might have missed this section along the way, which validates the answer `https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html#interacting-with-the-network`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My path were at this folder. So i fixed it with this command.

```
ricky@rr:~/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network$ export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
ricky@rr:~/fabric/fabric-samples/test-network$ export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/
```